# How to replace ® entity with &reg; in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html-entities

I have an old server with API and I need to load data from it to a new server. The problem is that an old server API outputs html entities like ®, I don't want to put those into a new database, instead I want to replace them with ® But I don't know how to do it in Rails. I tried to do it with HTMLEntities class but it does not replace it with ® Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the ® entity with `&reg;` using [**gsub**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub), e.g.

```
# encoding: utf-8 # this line might not be nescessary in Rails
string = 'test ® test'
string.gsub!('®', '&reg;')
# => string is now "test &reg; test"
```

Comment: Finally! Thanks a lot! The comment line on top did it! Without it rails threw errors about illegal character. Thank you

Comment: Run `sudo gem install magic_encoding` in your terminal. And write `gem magic_encoding` into your gem file. And `bundle` it.